# I understand that float elements have no height. So how do I accomplish the following?

Tags: css

I have the following CSS

```
        .myClass > div:nth-of-type(1) {}
            .myClass > div:nth-of-type(1) > div {}
                .myClass > div:nth-of-type(1) > div > div:nth-of-type(1) {float: left; width: 25%;}
                .myClass > div:nth-of-type(1) > div > div:nth-of-type(2) {float: right; width: 70%;}
```

which is not working because the floated elements are causing their outer element (namely `.myClass > div:nth-of-type(1) > div`) to have no height, causing rows to get their content to spill on top of one another. Is there any way without using float that I can keep the behavior of having `.myClass > div:nth-of-type(1) > div > div:nth-of-type(1)` and `.myClass > div:nth-of-type(1) > div > div:nth-of-type(2)` side-by-side with widths of `25%` and `75%` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use display: inline-block instead of float :)

```
.myClass > div:nth-of-type(1) > div > div:nth-of-type(1) {display: inline-block; width: 25%;}
.myClass > div:nth-of-type(1) > div > div:nth-of-type(2) {display: inline-block; width: 70%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe setting the parent div to `overflow: auto` would prevent the parent divs from collapsing.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
.myClass > div:nth-of-type(1) > div {overflow: hidden;}
```

The point is, you just need to enclose your floats (that is, force the container to wrap around the floated children). There's also the "clearfix" method for this.